# How to get pointer to string's data in a vector of strings?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I have a vector of strings as my primary data container. However, in order to interoperate with a C library, I need to be able to view these strings as character data pointers (i.e. `const char*`). This sounds simple enough, so I wrote a helper class like this:

```
class strvecAccessor {
  const std::vector<std::string>& names;

public:
  strvecAccessor(const std::vector<std::string>& a) : names(a) {}
  size_t size() const { 
    return names.size(); 
  }
  const char* item(size_t i) {
    auto name = names[i];
    return name.data();
  }
};
```

This accessor class is short-lived. It serves as a wrapper around an existing vector of strings, which is guaranteed to not be modified or go out-of-scope during the lifespan of this class. An example of how this class can be used is the following:

```
void test(strvecAccessor& arr) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", arr.item(i));
  }
}
```

But there is a bug in this code, which manifests itself only when I compile it in `--coverage -O0` mode, and only on Unix machine (I compile with CLang 6.0.0 in C++11 compatibility mode). The bug is that the printed strings contain garbage.

I believe what happens is that the `name` variable in `item()` method is not a reference, but a copy of the `i`-th element of the array. It goes out-of-scope at the end of the `item()` function, at which point the pointer that was returned becomes dangling. Most of the time it is not noticeable since the pointer is used immediately, but in coverage mode it gets filled up with other data right after the call.

The problem disappears if I replace `auto name = names[i];` with `const std::string& name = names[i];`. But I don't really understand why, and whether this actually solves the problem or just buries it deeper. So my question is: why the copy is being made in the original code; and how to protect myself against these kinds of errors in the future?

Comment: `auto name = names[i];` creates a new local `std::string` and `return name.data();` returns a pointer into a local variable ie a dangling pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - given that the penultimate paragraph points out the problem very well. Do you have a specific source of confusion?

Comment: I'm confused why `auto name = names[i]` is a new local string, rather than a reference to the existing string.

Comment: you missed && `auto &&name = names[i];`

Comment: @Pasha `auto` deduces the type from the RHS and `names[i]` is a `std::string` not a reference to a string (the reference of `names` does not propagate)

Comment: If `auto var = something;` would denote to a reference, how could you create non reference variable?

Comment: @Killzone Kid `auto&` is usually sufficient. `auto&&` is usually not what you want - you don't want to modify temporaries usually.

Comment: I believe the linked duplicate addresses your question? If not, lemme know.

Comment: @JesperJuhl does it not mean universal reference in this context?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I disagree - `auto&&` is usually what you want. Except when you want `auto`.

Comment: @Slava Yes. Except the term is _forwarding reference_ please.

Comment: @Barry is that official?

Comment: @Slava [Yes](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#def:forwarding_reference)

Comment: @Barry, good to know, thanks

Comment: Thanks, @Barry, this seems to clarify things. Although the link doesn't explain `auto&&`, it looks like I should have used `auto& name` or `const auto& name` here.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* item(size_t i) {
    auto name = names[i];
    return name.data();
}
```

Here, `name` is a local variable to the function `item()`, and you're returning an address to data that is owned by that local variable.  When it goes out of scope (the `item()` function completes) `name` will be destroyed.

Since you're guaranteeing the lifetime of the underlying vector, try this instead:

```
const char* item(size_t i) {
    return names[i].data();
}
```

This will be "safe", because `vector::operator[]` returns a reference to the stored data, and you don't make an extraneous copy into your `name` variable like in your original.

Comment: In meaning of C++ terminology `name` is not temporary, please do not confuse with your answer.

Comment: `name` is an lvalue, not a temporary/rvalue.